# How to specify values for a property in the Properties window in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, user-controls

What I am trying to do is create a ASP.net User Control with properties that someone else can change through the Properties window in Visual Studio 2010.  I have figured out how to specify default values using tags such as `<System.ComponentModle.DefaultValue(100)>` immediately before the `Public Propery`... but what I want is a drop down list in the properties window.

For example the `<asp:Button>` has a property named `ClientIDMode` and in Visual Studio 2010 I can click its drop down menu in the properties window and it will display different options: "AutoID", "Inherit", "Predictable", and "Static".

How can I create the same behavior in my own user control?

Comment: I believe you can do this by setting your property datatype to an `enum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Enum for that, there are other ways but this is a great start for you...

```
 Imports System.ComponentModel

 Public Class UserControl1

 Public Enum PetSize
  Big
  Normal
  Small
 End Enum

  Private myPetSize As PetSize

  <System.ComponentModel.Description("Select pet size")>
  Public Property PetSize() As PetSize
    Get
        Return myPetSize
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As PetSize)
        myPetSize = value
    End Set
  End Property
 End Class
```